# Circuit board layout: wifi ceramic antenna next to a electromechanical relay

Tags: rf, relay, wifi, layout

Is it okay to place a small ceramic antenna not far from a electromechanical relay? Would the magnetic field generated by the relay coil (when on) affect wifi operation?

clarifying edit:
not far = ~1 cm away (from casing)
both the relay and wifi will operate at the same time

Comment: What does "not far" mean?

Comment: made some clarifications in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more likely that electrical noise from the contacts switching will scramble the Wifi momentarily. If the relay switches infrequently there's probably enough safeguards built into the protocols that the effect won't be obvious.

[Here's](http://www.mbedded.ninja/electronics/teardowns/belkin-wemo-teardown) an example of a low-end power relay mounted a couple inches from a PCB WiFi antenna:

[image: http://www.mbedded.ninja/electronics/teardowns/belkin-wemo-teardown]

You may be better off than the above example with your ceramic patch antenna if you orient it so the ground plane is between the relay and the antenna.

Comment: "if you orient it so the ground plane is between" -- That orientation wouldn't be practically possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

How far away? What is the layout? How often does the relay switch? Do both systems need to be on at the same time?

As always the answer with design is - it depends on what trade-offs you are willing to make. If you provide more information then we can provide a better answer. With that said it's a bad idea. EM fields follow the inverse square law so the farther you can keep noisy components away from your RF components the happier you will be as a system engineer.

Comment: made some clarifications in the question. No layout to show yet, only brainstorming

Comment: What is the relay switching frequency? If it's anything last a couple times a minute I would expect poor WiFi performance.

Comment: It's not just about the relay's switching, it's about putting a chunk of metal in close proximity to an antenna - particularly when parts of that chunk probably share the same ground as the antenna.

Comment: actually the relay could stay on indefinately... what would be a good guideline for dealing with sources of magnetic field near these small antennas? oh, and yes - same ground